# How to create nested box in PlantUML?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I cannot make a nested box in plantUML.

```
@startuml
box "B0" #LightBlue
 Bob -> Alice : hello
 Box "B1" #LightYellow
  Bob --> Cunny : hi
 end box
end box
@enduml
```

This gives an error that box cannot be nested.

Any other way to show nested box, like in layered diagrams?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No luck yet.  :(

Comment: Update: Mar/2021 issue was not addressed yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems it's still not supported: http://forum.plantuml.net/6304/please-add-box-and-or-participant-nesting-ability

You can up-vote the feature request.

Answer (score 6):

It's been implemented and you can use it if you have v1.2022.0 or a newer release. The feature seems to be in an early stage and it needs the teoz engine.

Example:

```
@startuml
!pragma teoz true
box "component"
  box "sub1\n\n"
    participant a
    box "subsub1"
      participant suba
    end box
  endbox
  box "sub2"
    participant b
  endbox
end box
@enduml
```

[Github issue for reference](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/172) (The examples comes from here)